# directionally append an image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm looking to move an image tag across divs based on mouse click, I have created a tile grid system with two different types of tile - "deathsquare" & "mapsquare". The player can only spawn inside the "mapsquare" tiles and I'm trying to use this for the moment too.

Grid -

```
            <div id="28_25" class="deathsquare"></div>
            <div id="29_25" class="deathsquare"></div>
            <div id="30_25" class="deathsquare"></div>

            <div id="1_20" class="mapsquare"></div>
            <div id="2_20" class="mapsquare"></div>
            <div id="3_20" class="mapsquare"></div>
            <div id="4_20" class="mapsquare"></div>
```

This is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zCZkA/16/
I can't seem to move the player up the "mapsquare" classes using the onclick arrow. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't any code attached to the arrow?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wasn't clear I'm not looking for a solution because that would take a chunk of time. I was interested in methods I should research to approach this issue

Comment: Explain it more. I don't understand what you are looking for and what is the `deathsquare`.

Comment: One big problem I see is that your squares when rendered are not systematically located on your map.  So your id scheme doesn't relate to how they're actually placed. So moving one space in any direction is going to be almost impossible... http://jsfiddle.net/zCZkA/18/

Comment: So I have a background image and on top I have made a number divs, these make up the tile grid. I have two types of tile deathsquare & the mapsquare. deathsquare is just a tile the player cant spawn in on. (If you notice when you refresh the fiddle he spawns in a new location). The mapsquares are tiles I want to be able to move the player around on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to ensure that your rendered squares are systematically placed in order.  Your squares currently are not. After you have sorted out that issue you can keep track of where your player is like so...

```
$('#up').click(function(){
    var player = $('#player');
    var currentDiv = player.parent().attr('id'); // gets you 3_5 or something like that
    player.remove();
    //do logic to move up 
    var placement = currentDiv.split('_');
    var newSquare = [parseInt(placement[0])++,placement[1]].join('_');
    $('#' + newSquare).append(player);

});
```

Comment: How would you recommend I label the divs?

Comment: Your labeling is fine... its just how they get rendered:  jsfiddle.net/zCZkA/18  see how they're not in order....

Comment: What if I clicked the tiles instead of using the arrows, would that make it easier, or do I still need the current location of the player

Comment: They seem the label okay on the real live demo here - http://xronn.co.uk/battlearena/battle.html

Comment: Clicking would certainly be easier.  But it seems like you would want to be able to have arrow type controls.  Then you could even use keyboard keys to move around.

Comment: Hmm, thanks Bluetoft do you have a portfolio with your work on by any chance?